# Using charAt in a while loop Java

Tags: loops, while-loop, charat

My assignment needs to include name validation, including checking if there are any numbers in the name.  We are required to use the method as shown below - we are not supposed to use isNumber/isLetter.  What is below works fine, however, I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with the return values of true and false.  I'm an absolute beginner at Java - how do I interpret the true and false into something I can use?

```
public boolean stringNumeric (String name)
{
    int position = 0;
    while (position < name.length())
    {
        char thisCharacter = name.charAt(position);
        if (thisCharacter >= '0' && thisCharacter <= '9')
        return false;
        position ++;
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value as follows.

- return true means it do not contain any number value in string which you have 
  entered
- return value false means it contain atleast one numeric value

  ```
   boolean validate=stringNumeric(String_name);
   if(validate){
       //valid string ie doesnt contain any nos
     }else{
       // invalid string
     }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Ann - this wouldn't include the while loop and the iteration through each character that was entered, would it?

Comment: @user3448469 Its better to familarize with how functions are invoked.In the Above code we are invoking the method and return value is stored into a variable validate and  condition is checked against the validate variable